# Help! I can't think why it has to be closed as well.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

In section 9 of Terence Tao's book, we have the Heine Borel Theorem:-

> If $X  \subset \mathbb R$, it is bounded and **closed** iff any sequence of elements in $X$ has a convergent subsequence with limit in $X$

Everything's fine, it has a nice similarity with Bolzano - Weirstraß, but i cannot understand why it has to be *closed*?

---

My attempt to prove (the tougher implication) is like this-

Let $X \subset [-M,M]$.Then the sequence $(x_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ containing each element of $X$ is bounded, and letting $L^+$ denote the $\limsup (a_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ we have $|L^+|<M$, implying the limit superior is finite and thus it has a convergent subsequence with limit $L^+$.

It seems fine to me, but i can't understand why the condition "$X$ is closed" is necessary.

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: The claim as stated is false.

Comment: Umm maybe i missed out something, can you tell why?

Comment: The statement should be that $X\subset\mathbb R$ is bounded and closed iff any sequence of elements of $X$ has a convergent subsequence with limit in $X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it has a convergent subsequence. And the limit of that subsequence belong to $X$, since $X$ is closed. Otherwise, you cannot assure that that will happen.

Comment: Sir, Thats exactly i want to know, why won't it happen. I am having trouble here

Comment: Because, for instance, if $X=(0,2)$ and if $x_n=\frac1n$, then any conververgent subsequence of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ has limit $0$, which does not belong to $X$.

Comment: Can you clarify one thing for me? Like in some sequences, the limit is $\sup <a_n>$ while $\sup <a_n>$ may not belong to $X$?

Comment: Yes, that may happen. With the same $X$ as before, if $a_n=2-\frac1n$, then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\sup\{a_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}=2,$$but $2\notin X$.

Comment: Is it always necessary that the limit has to belong to the set?

Comment: No. Sometimes it is necessary, and sometimes it isn't.

Comment: So what is the contradiction if the limit as in your last example does not belong to $X$?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I never claimed that there was a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry, i completely forgot it said that the limit should belong to $X$ as well T-T So stupid of me! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.